# onInstall trigger wont run after installing add-on from G Suite Makrketplace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

I am putting together a simple Google Sheets Add-on for my internal domain. I have been able to install it from GSMP, but the onInstall trigger doesn't work. My document bound google app script works great when testing local to the document.

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen(e); 
}

function onOpen(e) {
  // Adds a text prompt to cells A1 and B1 calling for user to enter the label name to pull from, and the completed label name
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var cellA = sheet.getRange(1, 1);
  cellA.setValue("Add credit folder name to cell A2");
  var cellB = sheet.getRange(1, 2);
  cellB.setValue("Add completed credit folder name to cell B2");
}
```

Comment: Simple triggers can't do things that require permission like changing user data.  So onOpen() won't work .  You'll need an installable trigger.